# This image claims you can build "decentralized apps", and each computer "contributes a little to process it". Is that claim correct?

Tags: contract-design, blockchain, turing-completeness

[This image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Bbsb.png) claims that you can put decentralized apps (say, a messaging program) on the Ethereum network. It also claims that each computer on the network contributes a little bit to the processing of that app. That claim does not seem correct. Specifically,

1. I believed computation was expensive and anything but very lightweight logics (such as, `if condition is met, pay bob $10`) could realistically be put on the blockchain. Not whole complex apps. Is that wrong?
2. I believed that every computer on the network performed all the historical computation of all apps, which opposes the view that each computer does a little bit of the work. If that didn't happen, what would stop a participant to lie about the result of a computation?

Comment: Note that the image is for a non-technical friend/mother.  It is fine to ask clarifications, but non-technical information should not be construed to be technically accurate :)

Answer (score 19):

This image is a bit misleading.

1. Computation is not that expensive. According to the [stats page](https://stats.ethdev.com/), one gas is about 50 gwei, or 5x10<sup>-8</sup> ETH. A simple transaction is 21k gas, or 0.00105 ETH. A relatively complex application like [Augur](http://www.augur.net/) can easily function at these prices. Storage is more expensive, but most heavy-duty storage can be done off-chain, in [ipfs](http://ipfs.io).
2. You are correct, every node does every computation. The infographic is simply incorrect. In addition, only miners are rewarded, not every full node. There are [paralellization](https://blog.ethereum.org/2014/10/21/scalability-part-2-hypercubes/) schemes, in theory, but none have been implemented.