# Why do crypto-currency ventures pivot towards serving banks and what is Ethereum's approach?

Tags: blockchain, decentralization, enterprise

I am new to the world of blockchains. I worked briefly for a blockchain venture until they started working with banks. Not a judgement call, I am simply more drawn to crypto-currencies as a fuel for micro-economies rather than a tool to lower banks' operational costs. Today I visited Ripple's [website](https://ripple.com/), which seems to be the [3rd largest crypto-currency](https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/views/all/), and I saw it is very bank-oriented.

I wonder what makes blockchain ventures pivot to the banking industry? Is it only the fact that banks have a need for security which gives early stage ventures a clear financial path? Does the difficulty to ignite the masses' enthusiasm regarding decentralized asset systems play a role?

Regarding Ethereum, between serving the financial industry and bringing blockchain to the masses, does the Ethereum project have any stated desirable path or is it non opinionated?

Comment: This seems too vague and subjective to usefully answer.

Comment: I can see what you mean, I had put an effort to try and form my curiosity as a question. I guess if there is a focused inquiry here it would be - where are the Ethereum founders currently positioned world-view wise? Or to put it differently - would people be surprised if they pivoted to the finance industry?

Answer (score 3):

> does the Ethereum project have any stated desirable path or is it non opinionated?

Ethereum is non-opinionated because it is a platform for applications and computer programs.  Its generality, in addition to the technologies, is one of the things that can make it difficult to explain: [How would I explain Ethereum to a non-technical friend?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/45/42)

Cryptocurrency ventures pivot to banking because they are currencies.  An insight of Ethereum is that blockchain technology can be made to a platform, so that instead of just having banking or currency applications, anyone can write any type of application that makes appropriate use of a global public database (the blockchain).