# Is every Ethereum user already familiar with Bitcoin?

Tags: usability

What can be done to make Ethereum more approachable for those new to blockchain technology? I know a lot of people who are now interested in Ethereum but they had no idea what it was all about until they learned about Bitcoin first.

Is Bitcoin still a necessary stepping stone for learning due to its relative simplicity?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How would I explain Ethereum to a non-technical friend?](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/45/how-would-i-explain-ethereum-to-a-non-technical-friend)

Comment: I think this is more of a brainstorming question which works better on reddit a or quora.