# How Can I invest in Ethereum?

Tags: ethereumj

I saw some website selling cryptocurrencies:

1. If I buy Ethereum (ETH) what does that mean ?
2. What can I do with it when I buy it ?
3. Does that mean that I am investing in Ethereum or helping the industry ?

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to the Ethereum Stack Exchange!  Please check the tour http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/tour to learn about this Q & A site.

Comment: Welcome. The questions are flagged because they're just so far reaching. it won't be possible to answer in the Q&A format of this site but I found something that might be informative: http://meta.ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/431/refererence-answers-to-frequently-asked-questions/432#432

Comment: This, in particular: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/45/how-would-i-explain-ethereum-to-a-non-technical-friend

Comment: No problem, could someone send me private msg about it ? I see a lot of website selling ETH what does that mean if I buy it ?